# Oracle create table as select with count max condition

Tags: oracle, select, count

I've got an Oracle problem, here is my select:

```
create table new_table as 
select
idprod as product_id, descr as description
from old_table p where updateNum = (select max(updateNum) from old_table pp where pp.idprod = p.idprod);
```

this query gives me one generic error with no explanation. SQL Developer say me:

> "Error starting at line 7 in command: [...] Error report:
>   SQL Command: create table
>   Failed: Warning: execution completed with warning"

but create the table and the data inside seems to be correct.

Some hints?

Answer (score 7):

Older versions of SQL Developer have a bug which makes them issue a similar warning after a `CREATE TABLE`: see [this OTN Forums post](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=723332).

Since the table is created and populated with the correct data, the `CREATE TABLE` statement is correct. If you want to be sure, try executing the statement from SQL*Plus.

Comment: I started getting this warning/error message somewhere in the last few patches to Oracle 12c.  Currently seeing it with 12.1.0.2.0 and Sql Dev 3.1.0.7 but not in SQL*Plus.  I also don't see it against Oracle 11gR2.

Answer (score 7):

Oracle issues the "Failed: Warning: execution completed with warning" in a CREATE TABLE statement whenever you use a function on a column with NULLs. This often happens when you use a CASE WHEN or DECODE and don't use a default to take care of the NULLs (e.g., ELSE 0). This is also the solution to the same problem stated on https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=723332.

To avoid problems: make sure you don't use a function (e.g., max, sum) on a column with NULLs in a CREATE TABLE AS.