# Oracle DB & SQL Developer: "Error report: execution completed with warning" - How do I *see* the warning?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm setting up a local oracle (11g) database - a clone of another database we have running already. I'm running a bunch of generated PL/SQL commands in SQL Developer.

I get the output

```
Error starting at line x in command: 
*long-ass SQL statement here* 
Error report: 
SQL Command: force view "someViewName"
Failed: Warning: execution completed with warning
```

How do I read the warning that has been generated without modifying the script?

when I use the `show errors` immediately after this command, I get the output   `no errors`

Comment: I am having the same problem, with a CREATE TABLE statement.  I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14212342/450750) is relevant.  I don't think this "Warning" is anything significant.  I think it's one of those SQL Developer quirks (although I'm sure someone somewhere knows the exact answer).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If `show errors` doesn't give you anything:

```
select line, position, text
from user_errors
where type = 'VIEW'
and name = 'someViewName'
order by sequence;
```

That assumes you're creating it under your own schema; if not you can look in `all_errors` instead.

The columns are [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1085.htm#i1577005):

> `ALL_ERRORS` describes the current errors on the stored objects accessible to the current user.
>   `DBA_ERRORS` describes the current errors on all stored objects in the database.
>   `USER_ERRORS` describes the current errors on the stored objects owned by the current user. This view does not display the `OWNER` column.

Comment: *Note to others (like me)*: If you want all errors on views, you can use `select * from user_errors where type = 'VIEW' order by sequence;`

Answer (score -5):

The cause of the error is just simply forgetting your semi-colon at the end of your code.  Or if it is PL/SQL you are forgetting your forward slash at the end.