# create table statement resulted in "Failed: Warning: execution completed with warning" but no errors

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

My SQL code ran, seemed to work, but gave me a warning yet I cannot find the details of the warning.

I tried

```
    select * from user_errors and 
    select * from dba_errors and 
    select * from all_errors
```

When I did show errors, it said "No Errors."

I saw this in more than one place, and each time it was when the table being created was large or at least was created from a large or complex select. For now, I'd like to learn where else these errors are shown. Maybe I can ignore it, but would like to see what Oracle's concern was before doing so.

The SQL that fails is a create as select statement, I think notable is that the select could could contain millions of rows. I understand Oracle only allows DDL statements outside of PL/SQL (begin/end) blocks for a reason that I do not understand.  Nonetheless, I'd like to know if I'd get the same warning outside of PL/SQL as I would inside a PL/SQL block.

So, I need to be clear, the statement that failed was something like

```
CREATE TABLE USAGE_COUNT as (
    SELECT* FROM SOME_REALLY_LARGE_TABLE_1 T1
    LEFT JOIN SOME_OTHER_MEDIUM_SIZED_TABLE_2 T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

I really wish I could share the exact SQL, but I don't know how much I could get away with and I want to keep my job. But in this case, I'm not asking for specifics on how to fix the error or warning, only specifics on how to get the actual warning.

So to be clear, the statement that causes the warning is executed completely outside of any PL/SQL, and is directly invoked using SQLDeveloper in the worksheet. I do, however, have PL/SQL that I'm also writing, and I'd like to know where the error would show up had it occurred there as well.

Comment: `create table` is DDL (SQL), not PL/SQL - so where does the PL/SQL fit in, are you creating it dynamically? Please include the code you ran to get that error in your question.

Comment: Is the "PL/SQL code" a stored procedure, function, or package?  Or is it just a chunk of code you are running interactively?  The *_ERRORS views present compilation errors for stored code objects, not for anonymous blocks run interactively.

Comment: @Dave Costa I updated the question accordingly, but the code is a CTAS statement.

Comment: @Woodsman A CTAS statement is not PL/SQL, so we still don't know how PL/SQL is actually involved in generating the error. It may also be relevant what tool you are using to execute the code (SQLPlus or something else?).

Comment: What does `show errors` after the failing statement give you?

Comment: If you won't show us the code, you will have to extract the CTAS that is being run (for some reason) in a PL/SQL block and run that as plain SQL, and see if that still errors. I suspect your PL/SQL wrapper is an anonymous block that is either catching and mishandling an exception, or your client (which is...?) is handling the error/warning badly. I'd *guess* that your 'large and complex select' is put into a string variable that is too small, or you run out of temp/rollback space; but as you've given us no real information it can only be a wild guess.

Comment: Also "I understand Oracle only allows DML statements outside of PL/SQL" - I think you have that backwards; you can run DML or DDL outside PL/SQL; you can only run DML *inside* PL/SQL. To run DDL inside PL/SQL you need to use dynamic SQL, which seems to be what you are doing - perhaps unnecessarily.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It says "No Errors"

Comment: @AlexPoole I edited the question text to be more clear. The code with the error/warning is SQL, being run outside of any BEGIN/END blocks and inside SQL Developer. To be even more clear, it's also not inside any EXECUTE IMMEDIATE type instruction. I'm not looking for a fix (yet), but I'm looking for what it's complaining about. All it says is completed with a warning, but then it doesn't say what the warning was. The thrust of my question is, how do I get that warning?

Comment: @DaveCosta Thank you for the question. The code is not running inside a package, or even a code block, named or otherwise. It is not running as an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, either. It's directly being run inside a SQL workspace in SQLDeveloper.

Comment: I can't see how running that from SQL Developer (as script or as statement) would give that error. Idle thoughts - is there a DDL trigger? Is there a resource limit on your account that you're exceeding? What happens if you run the same CTAS through SQL\*Plus? What happens if you run the select part of the CTAS on its own (and let it retrieve all rows)? What version of Oracle and what version of SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: Via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835437/oracle-db-sql-developer-error-report-execution-completed-with-warning-ho, found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817177/oracle-create-table-as-select-with-count-max-condition/14212342#14212342 -- does that help? (The latter attributes the message to "Oracle" but I bet it is specifically from SQL Developer.  You could try running the same statement in SQL Plus to see what feedback it gives.)

Comment: That does sound like a clash between an old version of SQL Developer and a new version of Oracle then? (Hence some of the questions in my previous comment... *8-)